# $E$ stationary, $D$ closed and unbounded, then $E \cap D$ stationary.

Tags: set-theory

A subset $S$ of $\omega_1$ is called stationary if the image of every normal function on $\omega_1$ has a non empty intersection with $S$.

Let $E$ be a stationary subset of $\omega_1$, and let $S:= E \cap D$, with $D \subset \omega_1$ closed and unbounded. Prove $S$ is stationary.

What I got:

We first look at an arbitrary normal function $g: \omega_1 \to \omega_1$, then $D \cap g[D]$  is closed and unbounded. To see this, take a $\delta_0 \in D$, and a $\delta_1 \in D$ with $\delta_1 > g(\delta_0)$, and then take a $\delta_2 \in D$ with $\delta_2 > g(\delta_1)$. We go on with this, and let $\delta:= $ sup$\{ \delta_n \mid n < \omega \}=$ sup$\{ g(\delta_n) \mid n < \omega \} $, then $g ( \delta) = \delta$, and so $\delta \in D \cap g[D]$.  This shows that for every $\alpha < \omega_1$ there is a $\delta< \omega_1$ such that $\delta > \alpha$ and $\delta \in D \cap g[D]$. So $D \cap g[D]$ is unbounded. I also managed to prove it's closed.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I'd do in your situation is to prove (if it's not already done in the source from which you quote) that the ranges of normal functions $\omega_1\to\omega_1$ are exactly the closed unbounded subsets of $\omega_1$. So the stationary sets are exactly the sets that have nonempty intersection with every closed unbounded set.  Second, you should prove (if it's not already done in the source from which you quote) that the intersection of any two closed unbounded sets is again closed and unbounded.  That's essentially like the construction of $\delta$ that you gave in the question.  Once you have these facts, solving your problem will be easy.